# How to import tier pricing using CSV in magento 2

Tags: magento2, tierprice, magento-2.0.7, tiered-pricing

I am trying to import tier pricing for configurable product, example csv format is like below.

```
sku      tier_price_website  ALL GROUPS  tier_price_customer_group  tier_price_qty  tier_price
1000-101         1               1                0                     1                5
1000-101         1               1                0                     5                4.8
1000-101         1               1                0                    10                4.5
```

But while trying to import getting error like "**Please enter a correct entity model**"

Comment: try with only `sku , tier_price_qty,tier_price`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For import tier price,
Go To admin panel,

Choose Advanced Pricing from dropdown at below location,

> System -> Import -> Import Settings -> Advanced Pricing
>   Blog for import tier price,

**Select Add/Update from Import behaviour**

```
sku      tier_price_website      tier_price_customer_group  tier_price_qty  tier_price
1000-101   All Websites [USD]       ALL GROUPS                    1              5
1000-101   All Websites [USD]       ALL GROUPS                    5              4.8
1000-101   All Websites [USD]       ALL GROUPS                   10              4.5
```

You have to remove ALL Groups Column from your csv file and check again.

[Tier Price Using CSV Magento 2 Demo CSV](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-import-tier-pricing-advanced-price-using-csv-in-magento-2/)

**Issue with your ALL Groups columns. so remove from csv this column**

Comment: sorry still getting the same error

Comment: Please let me your import flow, what to do?

Comment: :did this is due to any version problem, do I need to upgrade magento 2.0.7 to magento 2.1

Comment: i have given solutions is based on 2.1, may be this create problems.., I havent try with 2.0.7

Comment: solves the problem when migrated to 2.1, but hope we need to make some more changes in the existing csv.

Comment: This is the completed format for import tier pricing using magento admin.

Comment: Now its ok , while giving integer values to tier_price_website and tier_price_customer_group like in my question getting error like csv is incomplete, any way thanks Rakesh this solves my problem.

Comment: can you please suggest me in my site something 4 lakh product and 10 tier price group so you no 1 product = 10 rows so how can I cover into the one roe in one product